# Is there a way to set the title in showFeedDialog?

Tags: facebook

I'm pretty sure the default title "Publish this story to your friend's Facebook Wall?" is incorrect. When the user publishes the story, it will appear on his and his friends' news feeds, but not on the walls of the user's friends.  I'd like to customize the title so that it doesn't contain a lie. Is there a way for me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no provided way to do that.  It's possible you could modify the DOM after the `showFeedDialog` prompt has been created, but you'd have to create your own JS to do that, and it might not be possible within the confines of FBJS.

I'm not sure where you see the problem with the title here however, unless it's a semantic interpretation.  The News Feed is a subset of the data that appears on the Wall of a user.  When a user confirms a feed dialog that is targeted at a friend, it will create a story on the Wall of the user as well as the Wall of the user's friend (and by extension be part of the respective news feeds as well), hence "publishing the story to your friend's wall".

Wall items do not show up on *all* your friend's walls... they are *your* wall items.  If a story is part of a news feed, as `showFeedDialog` facilitates, then the story will be picked up and put into all your friends news feeds... but it is never saved to your friends walls.